# How to do something after all asynchronous tasks finished?

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm using `AsyncTask` to download some files, and want to do something after all tasks finished.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep track of how many async tasks you have running and do something when the total is 0.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public int numOfTasks = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void addTask(){
        numOfTasks++;
    }

    public void removeTask(){
        numOfTasks--;
    }

    public void allTasksComplete(){

        if(numOfTasks ==0){
            //do what you want to do if all tasks are finished
        }

    }

    class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

            String responseString = "";
            return responseString;
        }

         @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                    addTask(); // adds one to task count.
                    super.onPreExecute();

            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            removeTask(); // subtracts one from task count.
            allTasksComplete(); // checks to see if all tasks are done...  task count is 0
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `addTask();` should be in `onPreExecute`, not `doInBackground`. The latter may execute multiple times.

Comment: I edited my answer to use onPreExecute as Eric suggested although I didn't see any documentation or examples of doInBackground executing multiple times and this has never been a problem in any of my own projects.  Either way onPreExecute will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask has a callback method name `onPostExecute`. It will be execute when the background task finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onPostExecute() callback when Asyn task finishes background processing, In a typical scenarion you would notify the UI (list adapter or UI Activity) that download of the File is finished and UI can refresh or populate the data.

> onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread immediately after the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing a progress bar in the user interface.

**Please have a look at this Android Ref example:**

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

**Example2:**

https://github.com/ashutoshchauhan13/TwitterFeedApp/blob/master/TwitterFeedApp/src/com/sixthsense/twitterfeed/ui/TwitterFeedActivity.java